# Change fontSize of an existing TextBox Shape

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a textBox in my Word Document, whose text is automatically populated through MailMerge - (the **`<<FinalName>>`** one in the below pic).

[image]

*The shape name of the TextBox is `namebox` (I got this from **Home > Editing > Selection Pane**)*

I was wondering if it's possible to change the font-size of this particular textBox - The textBox by default has a `fontSize` of **11**, and I should decrease it to **10**, depending on a variable's character-length (if its longer than 32 chars or not), so It could fit longer text more easily.

I have tried building some code myself, but I am getting a compilation error of 'variable not defined' on the `namebox` word.

Here is where I inserted the textbox:
[image]

```
Dim caName As String
Dim nameLen As Integer
caName = .DataSource.DataFields("Final Display Name").Value
nameLen = Len(caName)

If nameLen < 32 Then
    namebox.Font.Size = 10 'error - namebox variable is not defined
Else
    namebox.Font.Size = 11 'practically nothing changes here
End If
```

*As you can see, the value for `caName` is taken from a DataSource - this DataSource is also linked to MailMerge, so values will be the same.*

I have seen various examples, but most of them create a new textbox instead of using an existing one. How do I change the font-size for an existing textBox shape? Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

Comment: What is the **exact type** of the textbox? is it a `TextFrame`, `TextInput`, ActiveX `TextBox`, an VBA intrinsic TextBox, or something else? It will be displayed at the top of the VBA Properties window.

Comment: Hi, @Dai! Thanks for replying - unfortunately I am unable to find my textbox in the properties - [here's how my properties window looks](https://i.ibb.co/YZhz3B8/image.png) ; Also, I am unsure for the type of my textBox - I took it from [here](https://i.ibb.co/ssqjTZT/image.png). (the highlighted one, and designed it) Kindly guide... :)

Comment: That textbox is actually a `Shape`. You can start by getting the shape object in the document. Just paste this into your immediate window with the correct document selected to see a list of their names. `For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes: Debug.Print shp.Name: Next`

Comment: Hi @braX! Thanks for replying! I did a research on how to get/rename shape names, and found out that one can do this by going to **home** >> **editing** >> **selection pane**. I have renamed the concerned textbox shape to namebox. Now, how should I edit the font-size of `namebox` textbox-shape? Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "textbox" is actually a Shape with a TextFrame. You can get the shape object by name and change its font size (of the `TextRange` for its `TextFrame`) this way:

```
Sub Test
    Dim ShapeName As String
    ShapeName = "namebox" ' change this to the name of your shape

    ActiveDocument.Shapes(ShapeName).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 30

    ' to get the text that is in it...
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Shapes(ShapeName).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
End Sub
```

[TextFrame object (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.textframe)

If you are unsure about the name to use, print a list of the shape names in the immediate window using this:

```
Sub ShowListOfShapes()
    Dim shp as Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.Name
    Next
End Sub
```